# TypeError("Event data is not compatible with JSON type: {}".format(e))

Tags: python, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send and receive json data to Event Hub. But I am getting error: Event Data is not compatible with JSON type while receiving data. here is my send and receive code.

```
#Event_Hub_send.py
import sys
import logging
import datetime
import time
import os

from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Sender, EventData

logger = logging.getLogger("azure")

ADDRESS = "amqps://myns.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub"
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "mykey"

try:
    if not ADDRESS: 
        raise ValueError("No EventHubs URL supplied.")

    # Create Event Hubs client
    client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
    sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")
    client.run()
    try:
    employee = [
        { "name": "sankar", "age": 28 }, 
        { "name": "Madhan", "age": 21 }, 
        { "name": "Vishwa", "age": 32 }
    ]

        start_time = time.time()
        for i in employee:
            print("Sending message: {}".format(i))
            sender.send(EventData(i))
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        end_time = time.time()
        client.stop()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        logger.info("Runtime: {} seconds".format(run_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

While Sending I haven't received any Error.

```
#Event_Hub_Receive.py
import os
import sys
import logging
import time
from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Receiver, Offset
import json

logger = logging.getLogger("azure")

ADDRESS = "amqps://myns.servicebus.windows.net/myeventhub"
USER = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
KEY = "mykey"

CONSUMER_GROUP = "$default"
OFFSET = Offset("-1")
PARTITION = "0"

total = 0
last_sn = -1
last_offset = "-1"
client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
try:
    receiver = client.add_receiver(
        CONSUMER_GROUP, PARTITION, prefetch=5000, offset=OFFSET)
    client.run()
    start_time = time.time()
    for event_data in receiver.receive(timeout=100):
    data = event_data.body_as_json()
    print(data)

    end_time = time.time()
    client.stop()
    run_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Received {} messages in {} seconds".format(total, run_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    client.stop()
```

I Tried to receive the data as json. but throws Event data is not compatible with JSON type: No JSON object could be decoded.

```
    raise TypeError("Event data is not compatible with JSON type: {}".format(e))
TypeError: Event data is not compatible with JSON type: No JSON object could be decoded
```

So I tried change the method as `event_data.body_as_str()`. but I received the following response:

```
agename
agename
Received 0 messages in 0.263074874878 seconds
```

Can sombody suggest

Comment: From what I can tell, you are sending data not as a json object, I suggest you convert your employee entries on the fly to a json string and then send it. Receiving as a json should work. I may be wrong but give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
import json # add this 

for i in employee:
    print("Sending message: {}".format(i))
    sender.send(EventData(json.dumps(i)))
```

It seems that `i` is of type `dict` if that's the case the above should work.

Comment: you are right @Moshe Rabaev. One more Correction I did. created a new eventhub because the existing eventhub contains non json messages which it could not able to parse it. so why I created a new eventhub. Is there any way we can use the exisiting eventhub itself ?

Comment: I don't know azure yet, sorry.